# Efficiently computing all the perfect square numbers for very large numbers like 10**20

Tags: algorithm, numbers, sequence, square, perfect-square

Examples of perfect square numbers are **1,4,9,16,25....**

How do we compute all the perfect square  numbers  for very large numbers like 10 pow 20. For 10 pow 20 there are 10 pow 10 perfect square numbers.

So far what i have done....

Bruteforce :  calucate the x**2  in range 1 to 10 pow 10. As my system accepts just 10 pow 6.  This didn't work.

Two pointer  approach : I have taken the upper and lower bounds....

Upper bound is 10 pow 20

Lower bound is 1

Now, i have taken two pointers, one at the start and the other at the end. Then next perfect square for  lower bound will be

lower bound + (sqrt(lower bound) *2+1)

Example  : for 4 next perfect square is

4  + (sqrt(4)*2+1)= 9

In the same way upper bound will be decreasing

upper bound - (sqrt(upper bound) *2-1)

Example :  for 25 the previous perfect square is

25 - (sqrt(25)*2-1) =16

Both of the above mentioned approaches didn't work well because the upper bound is very very large number 10 pow 20.

How can we efficiently  compute all the perfect squares till 10 pow 20 in less time ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's easy to note the difference between perfect squares:

```
0   1   4   9   16   25   ...
|___|___|___|___|_____|
  |   |   |   |    |
  1   3   5   7    9
```

So we have:

```
answer = 0;
for(i = 1; answer <= 10^20; i = i + 2)
    answer = answer + i;
    print(answer);
}
```

Since you want all the perfect squares until x, the time complexity will be O(sqrt(x)), which may be slow for x = 10^20, whose square is 10^10.

Comment: what if there's some range in which we need to compute all those numbers. Lets say in range a and b where a = 10 pow 5 and b = 10 pow 20 ..we need to compute all perfect squares , then how should we implement this

Comment: Find the first perfect square bigger or equal to a. Then find the second. Take the difference between them and do the same thing.